# Oracle apex older version Scan QR Code Plugin Not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to use the plug in provided for QR Code scanner for lower version of oracle apex which is 20.1.
When using same plugin with latest version (21.2 or 22.1) it works correctly.
But when using same plugin with lower version it gives error.

Link is below:
https://github.com/RonnyWeiss/APEX-QR-Code-Scanner

Same plugin with latest version
[Check latest version image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBApz.jpg)

Same plugin with lower version giving error
[Check lower version error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZFdt.jpg)

I want to use this plugin in to lower version of oracle apex. How can I do that?

Comment: Contact people who developed that plug-in.

Comment: If you want to try to debug it yourself, the APEX Developer Toolbar is showing that there are errors.  Most likely, if you click that, you'll see errors in the Javascript console that will point you in the direction of the problem.  My wild guess is that some of the Javascript libraries that are used by the plugin require other Javascript libraries (or versions of libraries) that are not part of the older version of APEX.  It is possible that you could add those to your APEX project and that the plug-in would then work.